# Jcenter issue on using meowbottomnavigation

Tags: android, android-studio, repository, uinavigationbar

my first time developing an app but i immediately had a problem.

i was trying to add a "Meow Bottom Navigation" on my app but the problem is youtube tutorials always have this JCENTER repository but when i searched it has been shutdown already. i know nothing about these kind of things (repositories)

a. any tips on what to do regarding with this jcenter issue?
b. does jcenter being shutdown means i can no longer use meow bottom navigation on my project?

(i hope you understand my english, lol)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These repository handle storage of external dependencies for you. This means you are able to pull what you need from them at build time.

In your case, this seems easy as many libs of jCenter repos were mirrored in other repos (for example [Meow Bottom Navigation from MavenCentral](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.etebarian/meow-bottom-navigation/1.0.4)).

All you need to do to fix your problem is replace `jCenter()` repo from your top level `build.gradle` like this :

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jCenter() // -> replace by mavenCentral()
    }
```

Comment: thanks, it's good to know that it can be fixed easily!

Comment: No problem, also don't forget to mark question as answered if problem is fixed, thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Meow Bottom Navigation For Java Projects without androidx is deprecated. The docs are suggesting you to use Meow Bottom Navigation in Kotlin.
[1]: https://github.com/oneHamidreza/MeowBottomNavigationJava

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).